# VBA IF statement being skipped

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I've been toying with this very simple code and am completely baffled. Below are three different variations I have tried in order to figure out the issue and none have worked.

Original Code:

```
Sub GetResults()

Set Result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
Set UTDT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("UTDT")
Set RADAR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RADAR")

Dim y As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To RADAR.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To UTDT.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For y = 2 To Result.UsedRange.Rows.Count


If UTDT.Cells(i, 1) = RADAR.Cells(x, 1) And UTDT.Cells(i, 25) <> RADAR.Cells(x, 2) Then
Result.Cells(y, 1) = Trim(UTDT.Cells(i, 1))
Result.Cells(y, 2) = UTDT.Cells(i, 2)
Result.Cells(y, 3) = UTDT.Cells(i, 3)
Result.Cells(y, 4) = "Update"
End If

Next y
Next i
Next x

End Sub
```

I then remove the `and` portion and added a message box to simplify it:

```
Sub GetResults()

Set Result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
Set UTDT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("UTDT")
Set RADAR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RADAR")

Dim y As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To RADAR.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To UTDT.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For y = 2 To Result.UsedRange.Rows.Count


If UTDT.Cells(i, 1) = RADAR.Cells(x, 1) Then
MsgBox ("It WORKED!")
 End If

Next y
Next i
Next x

End Sub
```

Still skips the IF statement. So i decided ill change it to <> in case its skipping because invisible formatting is causing it to be false.. but still no luck:

```
Sub GetResults()

Set Result = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
Set UTDT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("UTDT")
Set RADAR = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RADAR")

Dim y As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

For x = 2 To RADAR.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 2 To UTDT.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For y = 2 To Result.UsedRange.Rows.Count


If UTDT.Cells(i, 1) <> RADAR.Cells(x, 1) Then
MsgBox ("It WORKED!")
 End If

Next y
Next i
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't given us much to go on. If it's "skipping" either the condition is never met or your loops aren't working as you expect.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint and stepping through your code to inspect the values when the `If` statement is reached. Also, use `if not UTDT.Cells(i, 1) = RADAR.Cells(x, 1) Then` to test the negative rather than `<>`.

Comment: If statement is never reached. It just runs the next. I have breaks on each step. Like I said above I did an equals and does not equal... Both skip the if. One should be true.

Comment: What is the value of RADAR.UsedRange.Rows.Count ? Is it greater than 2? Verify the same for the other two variables you use.

Comment: So I added my own data to help troubleshoot. For  UTDT and RADAR I just put "123" and it still said it did not match

Comment: I'm suggesting (as SJR did earlier) that your loop is not being entered.

Comment: That's the assumption but the troubleshooting I did should have solved for this. However I try to run today with no changes and it works... So we can close this I guess